# WTForms... html, autofocus?

Tags: python, wtforms

Is it possible to have some of the new attribute only attributes used in HTML5, inside of WTForms?

Eg, say you want to create a TextField with placeholder="foo", required, and autofocus attributes. How would this be done in WTForms?

In html it would look like this: `<input maxlength="256" name="q" value="" placeholder="foo" autofocus required>`

Note that `placeholder="foo"` is easily done in WTForms. `autofocus` and `required`, because they have no value, are .. well, as far as i've seen, not supported in WTForms.

Can WTForms support this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably need to create a custom widget.

Check out the [docs on custom widgets](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/widgets.html#custom-widgets).

Answer (score 30):

In WTForms 1.0, released yesterday, HTML5 compact syntax is now the default. Now you can do (in jinja):

```
{{ form.field(autofocus=true, required=true, placeholder="foo") }}
```

Note that in Jinja, the literal is `true` instead of `True` but if you were to try this in the python console you will need to use the python literal `True` for this to work.

In WTForms 0.6.x, which used XHTML as the default output, you could do e.g.

```
{{ form.field(autofocus="autofocus", required="required", placeholder="foo" }}
```

This is the recommended way for representing boolean attributes in XHTML, and this happens to still be 100% valid HTML5 and completely equivalent, though the HTML generated is a bit more verbose.

Answer (score 3):

I'm new with WTForms but it seems to me that the solution could be improved instead of using :

```
{{ form.field(autofocus=true, required=true, placeholder="foo") }}
```

use :

```
{% if field.flags.required %}
   {{ field(autofocus=true, required=field.flags.required, placeholder="foo") }}
{% else %}
   {{ field(autofocus=true, placeholder="foo") }}
{% endif %}
```

WTForms seems not to handle correctly `required=false` for 100% HTML5 and sets in the HTML an attr `required="False"` instead of removing the attr. Could this be improved in next version of WTForms?

Comment: A patch fixing the attr=false behaviour has just been merged into 2.0dev: https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/pull/17#issuecomment-28162938